# How to set parameter to postgres function using native query?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I created a native query where I use the postgres function *date_part(text, timestamp)* .
This is my code:

```java
String sql = "SELECT "
                + "(SELECT coalesce(count(*), 0) FROM public.cliente) AS totalClientes, "
                + "(SELECT coalesce(count(*), 0) FROM cliente WHERE date_part('year', dt_cadastro) = date_part('year', :ano) ) AS totalNovosClientes";
                
Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(sql);
        query.setParameter("ano", "2021-01-01");
```

The problem I'm facing here is when I try to set the parameter of the date_part function. It says that I need to add explicit cast for the "ano" parameter. I've already tried the following, but none of them worked:

```java
date_part('year', TIMESTAMP :ano)
query.setParameter("ano", "2021-01-01");
query.setParameter("ano", java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf("2021-01-01 10:10:10.0"), TemporalType.TIMESTAMP );
```

How to set the parameter properly?

Answer (score 1):

JPA specification does not support named parameters with native queries,but depending on what JPA implementation you use replacing the **:** in your sql string with **#** or **?**
might work.

In general for native queries the best practice is to use positional based parameters, e.g:

```
String sql = "SELECT "
    + "(SELECT coalesce(count(*), 0) FROM public.cliente) AS totalClientes, "
    + "(SELECT coalesce(count(*), 0) FROM cliente WHERE "
    + "date_part('year', dt_cadastro) = date_part('year', $1) ) AS totalNovosClientes";
                
Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(sql);
query.setParameter(1, "2021-01-01");
```